# wrong result when I pass a value from a service to my angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, components

I created an Angular service that contains a simple string variable, then in this service I update it's value in a function.
Then I call this function in my component.ts (by dependency injection), I got the initial value of my variable (the targed is to get the updated value)

this is the service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpService } from '../http/http.service';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
constructor() {}

callLogsToggle = 'on';
```

this is the function created in this service

```
public setHubspotTogglesStatus() {
 this.callLogsToggle = 'off'; //updated to off
}
```

this my component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'my-selector',
templateUrl: './myCompo.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./myCompo.component.sass'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private mySevice: MyService,
    
) {
   this.myService.setHubspotTogglesStatus()
   console.log(this.mySevice.callLogsToggle) //The result is "on" 
                                            //The variable is not 
                                            //updated
    
}
```

So any help to resolve this small issue ?

Comment: When are you calling the method to upadte the variable? You are only printing the variable value the constructor, which means you are going to print only the initial value. If you want to see the variable change, you must print it in another place

Comment: I did in my original code, and the problem is always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpService } from '../http/http.service';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  callLogsToggle:string;
  constructor() {
   this.callLogsToggle = 'on';
  }

  public setHubspotTogglesStatus() {
    this.callLogsToggle = 'off'; //updated to off
  }

  public getcallLogsToggle():string {
    return this.service.callLogsToggle;
  }
}
```

In your component.ts file

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'my-selector',
templateUrl: './myCompo.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./myCompo.component.sass'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( private mySevice: MyService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.myService.setHubspotTogglesStatus();
   console.log(this.mySevice.getcallLogsToggle());
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method expects 2 arguments but you are calling it with 0, try to remove the arguments of the function and call it at your constructor or pass the expected arguments for it.

Print any value at the service function that you are calling to check if it is reaching that function correctly.

Comment: Victor, I did what you said exactly, when I print the variable in the service after updating it, it shows me the correct result (value updated), but when I print it in the component.ts, it shows me the initial value

Comment: Could you try to create a blitz to reproduce it?